# How to modify notifyDataSetChanged to avoid onBindViewHolder being called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

Assuming that the current item we're displaying in a recycler view is always the correct one even if the index of it changes, how do we simply modify the data set without/or delay, the call to onVindViewHolder to the next time we swipe?

Comment: I didn't really understand what's the problem

Comment: @jensiepoo, try to describe your problem in other wording. "I have this, I want to achieve this, but I face this"

Comment: Calculate difference between old and new data set and call one of the specialized notify* methods https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html. Use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think we no need to modify `notifyDataSetChanged()` in this case. Just need to create boolean variable like:

```
boolean firstLoad = true;
```

then check it in `onBindViewHolder()` to skip the first time, set it to false to bind data in the second time we swipe (scroll)